# Results source not displaying items from Teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, query, result-source

We have a 3rd party intranet which uses SharePoint Online as it's back end, this is where our documents are stored. We have been using a library in a cassic SharePoint site to store documents displayed on the intranet, however, we are now moving everything to Teams and as such want to be able to do the same things with a library in a Teams site.

We have run into an issue where documents on *some* Teams sites are not searchable. I have a result source configured to look at the old SharePoint sites so updated this to point at the new Teams sites but the query returns nothing. What is odd, however, is that when pointed at other Teams sites it brings back items just fine. I can't see any significant difference between these sites, they are both private and were created by first creating a Team from Teams itself.

[image: Working Teams Site]
Working site

[image: Non-Working Teams Site]
NonWorking site

The only difference I've noticed is that under settings the site that does return results has the "Users and Permissions" section whereas the site which doesn't does not.

How might I go about diagnosing what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the Search and offline availability settings in the sites with issue ?

> On the site, select Settings Settings icon., and then select Site
> settings. If you don't see Site settings, select Site information, and
> then select View all site settings.
>
> Under Search, click Search and offline availability.
>
> In the Indexing Site Content section, under Allow this site to appear
> in Search results, select Yes to allow the content of the site to
> appear in search results.

And you can try to re-index the sites and try again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this is on in both the sites that are searchable and those that aren't.